# Pandas replace does not work with different numpy-int types even when values are the same

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, integer

I came across a strange problem today while debugging. Long story short, I have a clustering model which yields some labels to each observation. I want to change these labels according to their clustering-mean, such that the cluster with the highest mean has the biggest cluster-number and so on.

The issue is that my mapping dictionary-keys have `np.int64` as type but my series of labels have `np.int32` as type which causes the replacement not to happen (which I find very odd!)

See this example:

```py
maps = pd.Series([np.int64(0),np.int64(2),np.int64(1)]) #index-value should be mapped to series-value

# 0 0    0-->0
# 1 2    1-->2
# 2 1    2-->1

map_dict = {old:new for (old,new) in zip(maps.values,maps.index)}

map_dict == {0: 0, 2: 1, 1: 2} #True

labs = pd.Series([1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2]).astype(np.int32) #Simulate my list of clusters of observations

(labs.replace({0: 0, 2: 1, 1: 2}) == labs.replace(map_dict)).mean() #0.25
```

As you can see the `map_dict=={0: 0, 2: 1, 1: 2}` evalutates to `True` thus I would assume using either of those produces the same result.

Further more, this is odd:

```py
np.int64(1) == np.int(32) # True
1 == np.int(32) # True
```

i.e it shouldn't make a difference if I'm using `np.int64`, `np.int32` or just `int`. Actually, if I convert the `map_dict` to `int` like this:

```
.
.


map_dict = {int(old):int(new) for (old,new) in zip(maps.values,maps.index)} #cast to "int"

map_dict == {0: 0, 2: 1, 1: 2} #True

labs = pd.Series([1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2]).astype(np.int32) #Simulate my list of clusters of observations

(labs.replace({0: 0, 2: 1, 1: 2}) == labs.replace(map_dict)).mean() #1.0 - all of them gets replaced correctly
```

I'm aware that there technically is a difference between `int64` and `int32` (the number of bits) but I find the above very strange, that the two mapping dictionaries evaluate to `True` when we compare them but for some reason we have to use the exact same integer-type when using the `replace` method.

Also ususally the integer-type doesn't matter (I haven't had such a problem in Python before):

```py
pd.Series([np.int32(1)]) == pd.Series([np.int64(1)]) #True
```

Comment: Just a tip: `map_dict = maps.to_dict()`

Comment: ooh.. yeah. Thanks!

Comment: My bad. `map_dict = maps.to_dict()` does not produce the same output of your comprehension!!!

Comment: It does, just reverse order of "1" and "2" but the (key,value) pairs are the same

Comment: It's (probably) the same problem with [`Rolling.sum`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/36458)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the key type of `map_dict` and the `replace` function:

```
maps = pd.Series([np.int64(0),np.int64(2),np.int64(1)])

map_dict = {old:new for (old,new) in zip(maps.values,maps.index)}
for k in map_dict:
    print(type(k))

# <class 'numpy.int64'>
# <class 'numpy.int64'>
# <class 'numpy.int64'>

map_dict = maps.to_dict()
for k in map_dict:
    print(type(k))

# <class 'int'>
# <class 'int'>
# <class 'int'>
```

Use `replace`:

```
# with map_dict generate from comprehension
>>> labs.replace(map_dict)
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    2
6    2
7    2
dtype: int32

# with map_dict generate from to_dict
>>> labs.replace(map_dict)
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    1
7    1
dtype: int64
```

However when you use `map` instead of `replace` there is no difference on how the `map_dict` is built:

```
>>> labs.map(map_dict)
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    1
7    1
dtype: int64  # <- Note the cast from int32 to int64
```

Comment: That is correct - it is the type difference, which is what my entire question is about and what I have mentioned as being the problem ;-)  I just don't understand *why* it is a problem per my provided examples. That it works with `map` baffles me even more!